# Sentence Structure: Relative Clauses with "who"

Tags: relative-clauses

I can't analyze the structure of relative clauses.

> We are to look only to God, who as He wills makes angels "ministering spirits" to the heirs of salvation.

I guess

> ... who makes angels as "ministering spirits" to the heirs of salvation.

is plausible. If so, where "He" and "wills" comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"As He wills" is a *parenthetical* that describes how God makes angels "ministering spirits" to the heirs of salvation. You can rephrase it without "as He wills."

> We are to look only to God, who makes angels "ministering spirits" to the heirs of salvation.

*Will* when used as verb (and not a modal verb) has different meanings:

- To want or like
- To use the power of your mind to do something or to make something happen
- To intend or want something to happen
- To formally give your property or possessions to somebody after you have died

Comment: +1 Among them, *to want or like* is what is meant in the context. *Will* here may probably also be interpreted as *to use the power of your mind to do something or to make something happen*.

Comment: The meanings of inflected forms of _will_ are still modal (deontic modal, to be precise), but when it's inflected, it is no longer a modal auxiliary verb. This is the sense of _will_ when used in hypothetical clauses (_If he will hand it in, I will correct it_).